# Is it possible to draw violin plots in Qt/Qwt?

Tags: qt, plot, histogram, qwt

I am trying to implement violin plots using Qt. I have checked the internet for resources about the matter but so far I have only found examples that have been implemented using R and Python. Does Qt -or maybe Qwt for that matter- possess the relevant tools to implement these, or should I switch my platform? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt has a suite of various drawing tools, as violin plots are no different to any other diagram, you should easily be able to draw them yourself using `QPainter`.

Just to be clear, I'm talking about drawing violin plots, you will of course have to implement the math and data structures for them yourself.